# What is the transitive and reflective closure of the derivation relationship?

Tags: formal-languages, logic

*This question is asked during a class of Computer Science.*

> What is the transitive and reflective closure of the derivation
>   relationship?

I know that if $R$ is a relationship on $A^2$, a transitivive and reflective relation on $R$ is the following $R^*$

$$R^* = R^+ \cup \{<x,x> \mid x \in A\}$$

but I don't now how to apply it to the concept of derivation

Comment: "derivation" means different things in different contexts, can you elaborate? Are we talking about grammars in formal languages? Logical systems? Inference rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R\subseteq A\times A$ is a binary relation, it can be imagined as a directed graph: the elements in $R$ are the edges. The graph however might be infinite. The elements in $R^*$ represent (finite) paths, following zero, one or more of the consecutive edges. Zero edges because of reflexivity, two or more because of transitivity.

In case of a grammatical derivations the relation $\Rightarrow$ considered is a binary relation in $\Sigma^*\times\Sigma^*$ for some alphabet $\Sigma$, defining a single step as defined by the grammar. Then  $\Rightarrow^*$ consists of all pairs of strings the first one of which can be rewritten into the second, using zero, one or more steps.

In other words, $x \Rightarrow^* y$ iff there exist steps $x= w_0 \Rightarrow w_1 \Rightarrow \dots \Rightarrow  w_n=y$.
Again, this includes the case of zero steps $x= w_0 = w_n=y$.

This notation can then be used to define the *language* of the grammar. Usually [but not always] this looks like $L(G) = \{ x\in\Delta^* \mid S \Rightarrow^* x \}$; the set consisting of all terminal words ($x\in\Delta^*$) that can be derived from the axiom ($S \Rightarrow^* x$).